# PHP unserialize() Strange issue: Error at offset indicates wrong offset value?

Tags: php, serialization

I got this weird issue with unserialize(). I keep on getting this error : "Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 343405 of 769339 bytes in..."

Offset 343405 is "p" (the first character of "price" in the line below):

```
";s:5:"price";s:6:"$60.83";
```

the whole string is quite large (1 MB), it is being read from temp file on server, [LINK TO FILE](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/4yKgIpD1/0/blob?download)

I've spent over four hours on this and still cannot figure out what is going on, it appears that incorrect offset is given by the error. Is this possible?

This code is not new, and it has been working for many users (different data) without a problem. 
I produce the serialized string like this:

```
htmlspecialchars(serialize($data));
```

I read it as follows:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $data = stripslashes($data);

    $data = unserialize(htmlspecialchars_decode($data));
}
else{
    $data = unserialize(htmlspecialchars_decode($data));
}
```

In this particular case the magic quotes are enabled.

Any insights are highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you change php versions?

Comment: Why are you using `htmlspecialchars`? Are you displaying the serialized data on a web page?

Comment: @Maerlyn: No, this issue is with PHP5.3.28, this code has been working on a few dozen servers for about a year, PHP 5.3 - 5.4 no problem.

Comment: @Barmar: I do not recall why exactly now, I coded this awhile back, but I am certain it is needed there.

Comment: +1 for raising this issue in notice

Comment: Why does magic quotes matter for this? Magic quotes only affect data posted from the client. Are you getting this file from `POST` data? You said it comes from a temp file on the server.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a problem with handling multi-byte string. Try using custom unserialize function to workaround your problem:

```
/**
 * Mulit-byte Unserialize
 *
 * UTF-8 will screw up a serialized string
 *
 * @access private
 * @param string
 * @return string
 */
function mb_unserialize($string) {
    $string = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $string);
    return unserialize($string);
}
```

Besides, try setting [mb_internal_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) to make sure the internal character encoding is set correctly:

```php
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
$arr = array('foo' => 'bár');
$buf = serialize($arr);
```

Comment: This was a nasty problem, and your unserialze function was the on ONLY way I found around it.  Awesome tip

Comment: @MikeCrowe Thanks, Mike, glad being helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of error, however it doesn't explain incorrect offset given in the Notice, so I will not mark this answer as accepted.

The reason serialized string was broken is the use of `stripslashes()`. Old version of this script was sending serialized string via POST request, so the `magic_quotes_gpc` setting was relevant, hence the conditional statement. Now, however the serialized string is written to a temp file, then this file is read by another script so magic quotes are not used.